# How do I update VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Oracle VirtualBox on Fedora 17, and the program says that I need to update to the lastest version of VirtualBox.

How can I manage that? Unistalling VirtualBox and then installing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually as "easy" as that. Download the latest version and install it.

Your virtual machines and configuration are stored separately and won't be deleted. However, make sure to install the latest version of the VirtualBox guest additions after upgrading.

From the [VirtualBox forums FAQ](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=8669):

> **Q: What is the proper way to upgrade?**
>
> A: Since version 1.6.0, you no longer need to uninstall VB in Windows, but can install it on top of the current installation. This can be done by running the installer and follow the on screen instructions.
>
> For Linux Hosts, just run the install file (.dep, .rpm or what package manager you use) as root. The package will be updated automatically.
>
> For other systems, it should be the same procedure. The one exception to this is due to naming clashes: you do need to properly remove an OSE package if you are replacing an OSE version with a PUEL versions (for example because you need USB support).
>
> All VMs are kept during the upgrade or when you uninstall VB.